# Filter dataframe based on multiple groupings

Tags: r, dplyr

Each patient has two samples (R1 and TP); I want to identify columns (from "A" to "P") in which every patient has 'group == "R1"' >= 'group == "TP"'. Is this possible using dplyr/tidyverse functions?

**Table:**

| sample | group | patient | seq_type | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GLSS-19-0269-R1-01D-WXS-BMTNI5.vcf | R1 | GLSS-19-0269 | WXS | 123 | 75 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| GLSS-19-0269-TP-01D-WXS-G5IWER.vcf | TP | GLSS-19-0269 | WXS | 67 | 49 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| GLSS-19-0271-R1-01D-WXS-9657ZY.vcf | R1 | GLSS-19-0271 | WXS | 158 | 83 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| GLSS-19-0271-TP-01D-WXS-3TI55F.vcf | TP | GLSS-19-0271 | WXS | 87 | 50 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| GLSS-19-0272-R1-01D-WXS-E5JC16.vcf | R1 | GLSS-19-0272 | WXS | 127 | 79 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| GLSS-19-0272-TP-01D-WXS-9YKK98.vcf | TP | GLSS-19-0272 | WXS | 103 | 53 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| GLSS-19-0273-R1-01D-WXS-ZEKWL8.vcf | R1 | GLSS-19-0273 | WXS | 1535 | 750 | 21 | 27 | 31 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 21 | 25 | 31 | 2 | 1 |
| GLSS-19-0273-TP-01D-WXS-H00BNY.vcf | TP | GLSS-19-0273 | WXS | 100 | 49 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| GLSS-19-0274-R1-01D-WXS-IAULWM.vcf | R1 | GLSS-19-0274 | WXS | 145 | 70 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| GLSS-19-0274-TP-01D-WXS-F3BOIM.vcf | TP | GLSS-19-0274 | WXS | 108 | 55 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| GLSS-19-0277-R1-01D-WXS-OX9LZT.vcf | R1 | GLSS-19-0277 | WXS | 248 | 101 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| GLSS-19-0277-TP-01D-WXS-CK54HQ.vcf | TP | GLSS-19-0277 | WXS | 115 | 78 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| GLSS-19-0278-R1-01D-WXS-5MU7K1.vcf | R1 | GLSS-19-0278 | WXS | 175 | 88 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| GLSS-19-0278-TP-01D-WXS-59Y0J0.vcf | TP | GLSS-19-0278 | WXS | 72 | 51 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

**dput(df):**

```
df <- structure(list(sample = c("GLSS-19-0269-R1-01D-WXS-BMTNI5.vcf", 
"GLSS-19-0269-TP-01D-WXS-G5IWER.vcf", "GLSS-19-0271-R1-01D-WXS-9657ZY.vcf", 
"GLSS-19-0271-TP-01D-WXS-3TI55F.vcf", "GLSS-19-0272-R1-01D-WXS-E5JC16.vcf", 
"GLSS-19-0272-TP-01D-WXS-9YKK98.vcf", "GLSS-19-0273-R1-01D-WXS-ZEKWL8.vcf", 
"GLSS-19-0273-TP-01D-WXS-H00BNY.vcf", "GLSS-19-0274-R1-01D-WXS-IAULWM.vcf", 
"GLSS-19-0274-TP-01D-WXS-F3BOIM.vcf", "GLSS-19-0277-R1-01D-WXS-OX9LZT.vcf", 
"GLSS-19-0277-TP-01D-WXS-CK54HQ.vcf", "GLSS-19-0278-R1-01D-WXS-5MU7K1.vcf", 
"GLSS-19-0278-TP-01D-WXS-59Y0J0.vcf"), group = c("R1", "TP", 
"R1", "TP", "R1", "TP", "R1", "TP", "R1", "TP", "R1", "TP", "R1", 
"TP"), patient = c("GLSS-19-0269", "GLSS-19-0269", "GLSS-19-0271", 
"GLSS-19-0271", "GLSS-19-0272", "GLSS-19-0272", "GLSS-19-0273", 
"GLSS-19-0273", "GLSS-19-0274", "GLSS-19-0274", "GLSS-19-0277", 
"GLSS-19-0277", "GLSS-19-0278", "GLSS-19-0278"), seq_type = c("WXS", 
"WXS", "WXS", "WXS", "WXS", "WXS", "WXS", "WXS", "WXS", "WXS", 
"WXS", "WXS", "WXS", "WXS"), A = c(123, 67, 158, 87, 127, 103, 
1535, 100, 145, 108, 248, 115, 175, 72), B = c(75, 49, 83, 50, 
79, 53, 750, 49, 70, 55, 101, 78, 88, 51), C = c(2, 1, 6, 5, 
3, 2, 21, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1), D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 27, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), E = c(1, 0, 2, 1, 4, 1, 31, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
2, 2), F = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), G = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), H = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), I = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0), J = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), K = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), L = c(2, 
3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 21, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), M = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 
3, 25, 0, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1), N = c(0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 31, 2, 0, 
0, 2, 2, 1, 0), O = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0), P = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**What I've tried so far:**

(So many things. I'm still far from a solution. Do I need to pivot_longer?)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(patient) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), .fns = 'group == "R1"' >= 'group == "TP"'))
```

**Expected outcome:**

Dataframe excluding columns "D" and "L".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: See comment jaret_mamrot

With this approach:

1. data is transformed to long format with `pivot_longer`
2. `group_by patient`
3. sorted with `arrange`
4. new column `temp_TP = lead(value)` with `mutate` and `lead` so each pair of TP and R1 is side by side to compare for the condition.
5. remove every second row due to double data (because of `mutate and lead`
6. bring columns in friendly order
7. create a column `condition_check` where condition is checked with `ifelse` and a logical vector is returned.
8. Now you can identify all the columns that are `TRUE` for the condition with `filter` etc...

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = A:P,
               names_to = "A_P",
               values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(patient) %>% 
  arrange(A_P) %>% 
  mutate(temp_TP = lead(value)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %% 2 == 1) %>%  ## Select odd rows
  select(sample, patient, seq_type, A_P, temp_R1 = value, temp_TP) %>% 
  mutate(condition_check = as.logical(ifelse(temp_R1 >= temp_TP, TRUE, FALSE))) %>% 
  group_by(A_P) %>% 
  summarise(condition = sum(condition_check == "TRUE")) %>% 
  filter(condition == 7)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 2
   A_P   condition
   <chr>     <int>
 1 A             7
 2 B             7
 3 C             7
 4 E             7
 5 F             7
 6 G             7
 7 H             7
 8 I             7
 9 J             7
10 K             7
11 M             7
12 N             7
13 O             7
14 P             7
```

Comment: Thank you very much @TarJae - this worked with some tweaks: if you replace the `filter(condition_check == TRUE)` with `group_by(A_P) %>% summarise(condition = sum(condition_check == "TRUE")) %>% filter(condition == 7)` it pulls out the columns in which every "R1" is >= "TP", rather than just identifying the patients in which this is the case. If you could please edit your answer I will accept it. Thanks again for taking the time to work this out!

Answer (score 2):

If every patient has exactly two samples I find using base R more convenient here.

```
constant_cols <- 1:4
select_cols <- 5:20

df[,c(constant_cols, 
      select_cols[colSums(df[df$group == 'R1', select_cols] < 
                          df[df$group == 'TP', select_cols]) == 0])]

#   sample group patient seq_type     A     B     C     E     F     G     H     I
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 GLSS-… R1    GLSS-1… WXS        123    75     2     1     0     1     0     1
# 2 GLSS-… TP    GLSS-1… WXS         67    49     1     0     0     1     0     1
# 3 GLSS-… R1    GLSS-1… WXS        158    83     6     2     1     0     0     1
# 4 GLSS-… TP    GLSS-1… WXS         87    50     5     1     1     0     0     1
# 5 GLSS-… R1    GLSS-1… WXS        127    79     3     4     1     1     0     0
# 6 GLSS-… TP    GLSS-1… WXS        103    53     2     1     1     1     0     0
# 7 GLSS-… R1    GLSS-1… WXS       1535   750    21    31     0     2     0     0
# 8 GLSS-… TP    GLSS-1… WXS        100    49     2     3     0     0     0     0
# 9 GLSS-… R1    GLSS-1… WXS        145    70     2     3     0     0     0     0
#10 GLSS-… TP    GLSS-1… WXS        108    55     2     3     0     0     0     0
#11 GLSS-… R1    GLSS-1… WXS        248   101     3     3     1     1     0     0
#12 GLSS-… TP    GLSS-1… WXS        115    78     3     3     1     0     0     0
#13 GLSS-… R1    GLSS-1… WXS        175    88     2     2     1     0     0     1
#14 GLSS-… TP    GLSS-1… WXS         72    51     1     2     1     0     0     0
# … with 6 more variables: J <dbl>, K <dbl>, M <dbl>, N <dbl>, O <dbl>, P <dbl>
```

Divide the columns into two groups (`constant_cols` and `select_cols`). From `select_cols` select only those columns where all the values in `R1` group is less than `TP` group.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! This is the logic I am trying to implement, but I am trying to fit it into a larger 'tidyverse' workflow and would like to find out if it's possible using dplyr functions

Comment: I can translate the same logic in `dplyr` but I don't think it will fit in your larger `tidyverse` workflow since it would involve splitting the dataset into two,  comparing them with each other and selecting the columns that we need. For a proper `dplyr` solution I think we need to try a different logic.

Answer (score 1):

This works dinamically:
I get the amount of patients in which the condition is true, you can modify the condition, add more groups or letters if you want, and filter according to your expectations:

```
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(-sample, -seq_type) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(group, patient)
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = group
  ) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(
    condition = sum(R1 >= TP, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop"
  )
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 2
   name  condition
   <chr>     <int>
 1 A             7
 2 B             7
 3 C             7
 4 D             6
 5 E             7
 6 F             7
 7 G             7
 8 H             7
 9 I             7
10 J             7
11 K             7
12 L             6
13 M             7
14 N             7
15 O             7
16 P             7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Alvaro-Morales! This works perfectly on the MRE. In my actual use-case I need to keep "sample" and "seq_type" for plotting further down the pipeline, so I will need to tweak this approach, but I really appreciate the effort!

Comment: I think I could do that.